# Container view with freeform doesn't resize when constraints are applied

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicontainerview

I am currently using a container views for my project( 721*1024)
and i have an image-view that goes end to end and has height 44.
if i apply constraints to this image view it re-sizes correctly in the normal iPad view
i.e 768*1024
but if i use a free form container view and apply the same constraints it doesn't re-size.
What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you applied all the constraints. Left, right, top, bottom, height, etc?

Comment: @Tander yes i have applied all the constraints